# Javascript in VSCode Jupyter notebook not showing output

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using VS Code, and was wondering if the Jupyter Notebook support also supports Javascript. Looking around online it looks like it should, but I am unable to produce any output.

This python code shows output "test":

```
print("test")
```

This JS code does not show any output:

```
%%javascript
console.log("test");
```

This JS code also does not show any output:

```
%%javascript
element.text("test");
```

And because I'm desparate, I've also tried this:

```
%%javascript
element.text = "test";
```

I have no clue what it is I am doing wrong...

VS Code, Python extension and Jupyter extension are all up to date.

Comment: have you found the solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: sadly, no answers found yet :-(

Comment: I posted an answer, not really sure if it works for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using:

```
%%script node   
console.log("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, the Javascript console is available through `Help > Toggle Developer Tools`, then on the `Console` tab. You'll see the `console.log` output appear (VSCode is based on Chromium, so it should be familiar if you ever used the Chrome JS console).

If you want the output to appear in the notebook, you can use javascript to update the HTML output, like:

```py
%%html
<div id='abcd'></div>

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('abcd');
elem.innerHTML = 'Some text';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I started using this extension and it is working perfectly.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostfields.nodejs-repl

I think it is not the same as Jupyter but it was enough for me.

Comment: The thing I like specifically about Jupyter Notebooks is that they are a sort of 'interactive documents', which is great for the introductory programming course I teach in high-school. It would be amazing for me if I can provide students with the same type of document when I want to switch to Javascript with them.